# using "touch" to create directories?

Tags: linux, bash

1) in the "A" directory:

find . -type f > a.txt

2) in the "B" directory: 
cat a.txt | while read FILENAMES; do touch "$FILENAMES"; done

3)
Result: the 2) "creates the files" [i mean only with the same filename, but with 0 Byte size] ok. But if there are subdirs in the "A" directory, then the 2) can't create the files in the subdir, because there are no directories in it.

Question: is there a way, that "touch" can create directories?

Comment: Cross-posted on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/223267/using-touch-to-create-directories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is your desired end result?

If you are trying to duplicate a directory structure there are easier ways. Syncing solutions come to mind first.

e.g.

```
rsync -a /source/dir/ /dest/dir/ --include \*/ --exclude \*
```

This will recreate the entire directory structure. You can then run your touch command to finish the rest.

As previously mentioned we may be able to find a more elegant solution if we know the full problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use this script. You need to use `chmod +x scriptname`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# touchMakingDirs: a Ruby script to be able to touch a file and optionally create the directories necessary
# by Dan Rosenstark 2013-03-18 
if __FILE__ == $0
  if ARGV.length == 0
    puts "Sorry, include one argument for filename"
    exit
  end

  filename = ARGV[0]
  puts "Will touch file #{filename}"
  path = File.dirname(filename)
  #filename = File.basename(filename)  
  `mkdir -p \"#{path}\"`
  `touch \"#{filename}\"`
end
```

It's worked in a few small tests. Let me know if there is a test case I've missed. I use it like: `touchMakingDirs blah/blah/whatever/who.txt` where I've named the script touchMakingDirs and put it in my path.